# Problema con jQuery Ajax y PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un registro en la BD sin que me recargue la página. El registro se guarda correctamente, pero cuando quiero capturar la respuesta se muestra el documento PHP.

**Código js**

```
$('#btnagregarO').click(function(){
var obs = $("#txtob").val();
var cliente = $("#txtcli").val();  

var datos = "obs="+obs+"&cliente="+cliente;      

$.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'Usuario.php',
        data        : datos,            
        success:function(resp){                    
            alert(resp); 
        }                
    });
event.preventDefault();
```

});

Fichero PHP:

```
$u->conexion();


$sql = "insert observacion values(NULL,'$Obs',$N,'$usu','$fecha')";     
$sentencia = $u->m->query($sql);                             
if($u->m->affected_rows > 0){

    echo "Se pudo registrar";                
}else{

    echo "No se pudo registrar";
} 
$u->desconexion();
```

Ojala me ayuden que primera vez que el uso de ajax y no se que puede estar mal.

Comment: perdón el código no sé porque pero me sale así, tal ves por lo que estoy por el celular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno mira deberías usar la función html() que captura la respuesta de php de la siguiente manera.

```
$('#btnagregarO').click(function(){
var obs = $("#txtob").val();
var cliente = $("#txtcli").val();  

var datos = "obs="+obs+"&cliente="+cliente;      

$.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'Usuario.php',
        data        : datos,            
        success: function(data){                    
            $(".resul-post-edit").html(data);              
    });
event.preventDefault();
```

**para capturar los resultados los metes dentro de un div así**

```
<div class="resul-post-edit"></div>
```

**corregido**

Comment: Lo probé y no me muestra nada dentro del div

Comment: revisaste que tenía mal mi class="resul-post-edit" ?

Comment: $('#btnagregarO').click(function(){
var obs = $("#txtob").val();
var cliente = $("#txtcli").val();  

var datos = "obs="+obs+"&cliente="+cliente;      

$.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'Usuario.php',
        data        : datos,            
        success: function(data){                    
            $(".resul-post-edit").html(data);              
    });
event.preventDefault();

Comment: era que tenía una } de más en donde se ejecuta el contenedor div

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono :)

Comment: con gusto, saludos de colombia :)